# Copy folder context menu requires user input

Tags: windows, scripting, shell

We copy a lot of data around in our organisation, and we like using RoboCopyPlus for the robustness and the email reports at the end.

I've added the RoboCopyPlus string to the folder context menu in the registry as:

```
cmd /c robocopyplus "%1" "C:\Data" *.* /s
```

But that means I can only copy a folder to C:\Data.

What's the best way to prompt for user input or create a variable that I can pass in to the command? Ideally I would like a folder browser dialogue to pop up and ask them the location, but accepting that that's probably complicating the matter, how would I prompt for user input in the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a simple application to have the user select a file, then launch RoboCopyPlus using the path that was selected. Add an entry to your context menu that launches this application instead. Here's an example in C# using the [`FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) class and [`Process.Start()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace RobocopyLauncher
{
    class Launcher 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog browser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (browser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && args.Length == 1)
            {
                // Not sure of the exact command but it would be 
                // something like this
                Process.Start(string.Format("robocopyplus \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", 
                    args[0], browser.SelectedPath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Donut. That gets me really close - I had to add [STAThread] above the Main method, but it will pop up the FolderBrowser now. Unfortunately, it won't start the process. I suspect that's because the string called by Process.Start isn't correct, but I can't find a way to verify exactly what the string is outputting. Could you tell me what {0} and {1} should be?

Comment: David, I'd have to see the documentation for RoboCopyPlus, and I couldn't find it online. In my example, `{0}` is `args[0]` -- the path you're trying to copy from, and `{1}` is `browser.SelectedPath` -- the path you're trying to copy to.  Do you have documentation of the command line arguments that RoboCopyPlus supports anywhere?

Comment: Donut, RoboCopyPlus is a wrapper for RoboCopy, and uses the same syntax: http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/05/07/robocopy-syntax-command-line-switches-and-examples/ gives you the details for the syntax, but it is basically as you specified. 

The exact syntax being passed to the process is therefore (excluding square brackets) [robocopy "C:\Data\" "C:\Data2\"]. If I replace the two arguments with hard-coded folder paths, then on running the process it should copy the data, right?